# How can I refer to the current index while iterating an array in batch?

Tags: batch-file

When I try iterating the folders with a for each approach I have no access to the current index and I've also failed to manually keep one:

```
@echo off

set "i=0"
set folders='dir /b /ad'
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%D in (%folders%) do (
    :: echo %%D
    echo %i%
    set /a "i+=1"
)
```

When I try iterating with a fori approach based on [this example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_arrays.htm) I can't even get it working:

```
@echo off
cls

set "i=0"
:SymLoop
set folders='dir /b /ad'
if defined folders[%i%] (
    echo %%folders[%i%]%%
    set /a "i+=1"
    GOTO :SymLoop
)
```

I'm aware of my total lack of knowledge on the topic so I'd appreciate any kind of correction and/or advice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
@echo off

set /a i=0
set folders='dir /b /ad'
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%D in (%folders%) do (
    REM echo %%D
    CALL echo %%i%%
    CALL SET "folders[%%i%%]=%%D"
    set /a i+=1

)
SET fol

ECHO ---------------------------

@echo off

set /a i=0
:SymLoop
set folders='dir /b /ad'
if defined folders[%i%] (
    CALL echo %%folders[%i%]%%
    set /a "i+=1"
    GOTO SymLoop
)


GOTO :EOF
```

Please refer to endless examples on SO about `delayed expansion` for simpler ways.

Not a good idea to use `::-comments` within a `(code block)` as it can break the block.

`set /a` does not ordinarily require "quotes"